# Buttons Publish and Cancel don't work in Mediawiki's WikiEditor extension

Tags: mediawiki

It's a question about the [WikiEditor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWikiEditor) extension for Mediawiki.
I activated the publish module to display in the top right corner the buttons Publish and Cancel :

```
$wgDefaultUserOptions['wikieditor-publish'] = 1;
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected : the Publish button does nothing and the Cancel button does publish.
I looked into the jquery.wikiEditor.publish.js file but I don't really understand the publish module code source :

```
context.fn.addButton( {
    'captionMsg': 'wikieditor-publish-button-publish',
    'action': function () {
        $( '#' + dialogID ).dialog( 'open' );
        return false;
    }
} );

context.fn.addButton( {
    'captionMsg': 'wikieditor-publish-button-cancel',
    'action': function () { }
} );
```

Does anyone know how it works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been added to bugzilla : https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42198
And a fix has been commited : https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/44989

So the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this in MediaWiki 1.20.0 with a quick hack, changing the code to read:

```
context.fn.addButton( {
  'captionMsg': 'wikieditor-publish-button-publish',
  'action': function () {
    $( '#' + dialogID ).dialog( 'open' );
  }
} );

context.fn.addButton( {
  'captionMsg': 'wikieditor-publish-button-cancel',
  'action': function () {
    window.location = $("*").find("a[id='mw-editform-cancel']").first().attr("href");
    return false;
  }
} );
```

This makes both buttons work as expected for me, and should work in 1.19 as well. Someone who actually knows jQuery could probably do this better.

Just for the record, the code to change is found at the end of the following file in your Mediawiki distribution:

```
extensions/WikiEditor/modules/jquery.wikiEditor.publish.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you explain the source code you changed? Because I still don't understand the original and yours.